# Necesito ayuda con el menu y los submenues en el panel de administración de un plugin de Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Necesito que el menu me aparezca como se muestra en el ejemplo siguiente

[image: No se repite la palabra Ajustes]

Ese es el menu Ajustes por defecto de Wordpress, si ven que la opcion "Ajustes" no se repite en el submenu, a diferencia del mio, que si se repite

[image: Quisiera eliminar la opcion "Chatbot settings del submenu"]

No se que debo hacer, he probado de todo, se supone que la opcion Chatbot Settings solo es una opcion que mostrara el submenu, y no tendra ninguna pagina como tal, que puedo hacer, ayuda. Aqui dejo el codigo que genera los menus

```
add_menu_page(
        'Chatbot Settings',          // Titulo de la Pagina
        'ChatBot Settings',          // Texto a mostrar en el menu
        'administrator',             // Persona que puede entrar
        'chatbot_settings',          // ID del menu en URL
        'chatbot_settings',          // Funcion que llamara para pintar la pantalla 
        'dashicons-admin-generic'    // Icono que se mostrara en la pantalla
    );

    add_submenu_page( 
        'chatbot_settings',          // ID de URL de menu padre
        'ChatBot Users',             // TItulo de la pagina
        'Chat in Corso',             // Texto a mostrar en submenu 
        'administrator',             // Persona que puede entrar
        'chatbot_users',             // ID del submenu en URL
        'chatbot_users'              // Funcion que llamara para pintar la pantalla
    );

    add_submenu_page( 
        'chatbot_settings',          // ID de URL de menu padre
        'ChatBot Users',             // TItulo de la pagina
        'BOT',                       // Texto a mostrar en submenu 
        'administrator',             // Persona que puede entrar
        'chatbot_bot',               // ID del submenu en URL
        'chatbot_bot'                // Funcion que llamara para pintar la pantalla
    );

    add_submenu_page( 
        'chatbot_settings',          // ID de URL de menu padre
        'ChatBot User History',      // TItulo de la pagina
        'Storico',                   // Texto a mostrar en submenu 
        'administrator',             // Persona que puede entrar
        'chatbot_user_history',      // ID del submenu en URL
        'chatbot_user_history'       // Funcion que llamara para pintar la pantalla
    );

    add_submenu_page( 
        'chatbot_settings',          // ID de URL de menu padre
        'ChatBot Import',            // TItulo de la pagina
        'Impostazioni',              // Texto a mostrar en submenu 
        'administrator',             // Persona que puede entrar
        'chatbot_import',            // ID del submenu en URL
        'chatbot_import'             // Funcion que llamara para pintar la pantalla
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he corregido
Les dejo el codigo que utilize, solo era una tonterias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
add_menu_page(
        '',                          // Titulo de la Pagina
        'CHAT',                      // Texto a mostrar en el menu
        'administrator',             // Persona que puede entrar
        'chatbot_users',             // ID del menu en URL
        'chatbot_users',             // Funcion que llamara para pintar la pantalla 
        'dashicons-admin-generic'    // Icono que se mostrara en la pantalla
    );

    add_submenu_page( 
        'chatbot_users',          // ID de URL de menu padre
        'ChatBot Users',             // TItulo de la pagina
        'Chat in Corso',             // Texto a mostrar en submenu 
        'administrator',             // Persona que puede entrar
        'chatbot_users',             // ID del submenu en URL
        'chatbot_users'              // Funcion que llamara para pintar la pantalla
    );

    add_submenu_page( 
        'chatbot_users',          // ID de URL de menu padre
        'ChatBot Users',             // TItulo de la pagina
        'BOT',                       // Texto a mostrar en submenu 
        'administrator',             // Persona que puede entrar
        'chatbot_bot',               // ID del submenu en URL
        'chatbot_bot'                // Funcion que llamara para pintar la pantalla
    );

    add_submenu_page( 
        'chatbot_users',          // ID de URL de menu padre
        'ChatBot User History',      // TItulo de la pagina
        'Storico',                   // Texto a mostrar en submenu 
        'administrator',             // Persona que puede entrar
        'chatbot_user_history',      // ID del submenu en URL
        'chatbot_user_history'       // Funcion que llamara para pintar la pantalla
    );

    add_submenu_page( 
        'chatbot_users',          // ID de URL de menu padre
        'ChatBot Import',            // TItulo de la pagina
        'Impostazioni',              // Texto a mostrar en submenu 
        'administrator',             // Persona que puede entrar
        'chatbot_import',            // ID del submenu en URL
        'chatbot_import'             // Funcion que llamara para pintar la pantalla
    );
```